# Vertex Shader and fragment failed to compile, conflict with main

Tags: c++, opengl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

Backstory : Yesterday, I hangout[whatever that google plus video chat called] with the guy, who is showing me about OPENGL ES for developing game on Android. I got inspired to learn OPENGL from him and started right of yesterday.

Google some tutorial on Opengl, got this link https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32876/good-resources-for-learning-modern-opengl-3-0-or-later and follow the wiki one 'til this lesson:http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_02 where they load shader and vertex from the file. This is where i got problem.

The compiler keeps telling me on the vertex and fragment shader file that 'main has to return int'(the new std states so maybe)-a main conflict, how do you resolve this problem?

Note : I am using Qt

Comment: From the issue about `main`, It sounds like you haven't understood some of the basics of C/C++. Without isolating some code, there's no way to answer this question.

Comment: @BrettHale: He's referring to GLSL shaders. Their entry point is called main as well, but, well, that's not the problem. See my upcoming answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like you added your shader source files to the list to be compiled by the C++ compiler. *You are not supposed to do this!*

OpenGL shaders are compiled at runtime, by the GLSL compiler contained in the OpenGL implementation. The files you have your shaders in, they're just ordinary text files. You read them, pass them to OpenGL. You do not process them when building the program.

Comment: It worked now. Thank. For some weird reason, Qt compile both these files too.

Comment: @DucHoDucHo: Qt is not compiling anything. It's a framework library. You're probably referring to "Qt Creator", an IDE developed by the Qt Project.